# Что такое BindingSource

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Не могу понять, что такое `BindingSource`. Через адаптеры мы можем манипулировать данные. Тогда зачем нам `BindingSource` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная задача компонента BindingSource - обеспечить унифицированный доступ к источнику данных.
Но он также помогает использовать несколько возможностей:

1. В случае привязки DataTable к BindingSource появляется возможность сортировки, фильтрации и поиска.
2. BindingSource может являться источником данных не только для элементов управления, но и для самого BindingSource.
3. Вы можете работать с одним источником данных, привязанным ко многим элементам управления.

Для ответа использовал [BindingSource - what are the advantages of using BindingSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956937/bindingsource-what-are-the-advantages-of-using-bindingsource) и [Data Binding for Windows Forms](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84476/data-binding-for-windows-forms/).

Справочная информация по вопросу: [Компонент BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h974h4y2(v=vs.110).aspx).